# WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1/ws' failed when run web app

Tags: node.js, websocket

I have a nodejs web app with websocket , when i run on localhost it's not problem but when i run on public host (have SSL,domain name...) i get error : WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1/ws' failed .

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Same issue here but i get it on all websites i visit publicly. Could this be a firewall thing?
things i've tried for now without success:
- reinstalled chrome
- reinstalled xampp
- restarted computer... my question is the same except i don't have a web app, it occurs on all public websites. I don't get it at all...

Answer (score 0):

Question here is, where are you trying to connect from

Client OR Server

The error message would indicate you are trying to connect to a localhost, so if you are getting this message back from the client side, then its because your connecting to a non-reachable WS instance. Also, if you WS host is https, you would use WSS protocol vs just WS

As mentioned, without seeing the code its hard to tell

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup your server environment, is your web-server (Apache, nginx) correctly pass requests from world to your node app?..
Is your server firewall pass WS connections?..
IMHO you need a consultation from your provider DevOp's support team.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the following according to your statement:
`ws://127.0.0.1/ws`

From what I have read in the various ws api's while researching my own websocket issues I believe you would need to make the following change:

`wss://127.0.0.1/ws`

as wss is used for SSL connections.